# подпись приложений для google play. PEPK

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, google-play-console

Всем привет, прошу помощи. Пытаюсь по инструкции гугла создать подпись через PEPK, но он уже вторые сутки не поддаётся
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую такую команду, но думал что вместо [Что вводить тут?] нужно вводить пароль от ключа  и пароль от алиаса, но вы выходит. Что бы там я не уазал, потом он от этого имени спрашивает пароль (попробовал ради теста ввести 123 вместо [Что вводить тут?] )
Enter password for store '123': =(
Подскажите правильный синтаксис команды, правильно что вместо .keystore я указываю key.jks?

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1\bin\java" -jar C:\newKey\fromGoogle\pepk.jar --keystore=C:\newKey\key.jks --alias=driver --output=C:\newKey\fromGoogle\ --signing-keystore=[Что вводить тут?] --signing-key-alias=[Что вводить тут?] --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=C:\newKey\fromGoogle\encryption_public_key.pem